# Getting the text of a bootstrap flash message with JQuery (without the x)

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the text of a bootstrap flash message without the "x" and the html and it's giving me strange results.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-info fade in">
  <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
  Your post has been saved.
</div>
```

When I use jquery (e.g.):

```
$(".alert").text();
```

This is the result:

```
"
    ×
    Your post has been saved.
  "
```

As you can see, I'll also get the x (which is of course logical to me) but also a lot of strange spaces and new lines. So how can I only get the "Your post has been saved" string (without the x and without the spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the text you care about in a `<span>` then use the selector `.alert span` in your jquery statement.

Like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-info fade in">
<button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
<span>Your post has been saved.</span>
</div>
```

then:

```
$(".alert span").text();
```

You could also use `"alert :not(button)"` as your selector if you can't modify the html.

Comment: Oh my god, I feel like an idiot. Thank you :). (I actually thought that I cannot edit the bootstrap html but I easily can). But thanks anyway for your edit (with the :not part, that's actually interesting).

Comment: lol, no problem. [I had to look it up](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)